# Creating Ascii Art using for-loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, ascii

I need to write code that uses for loops to create the following(legs for a person):

> ```
>      /***/    \***\
>    /****/      \****\
>  /*****/        \*****\
> ```

This should be in a private method (ie. createLegs), the spaces along the left of the legs need to decrease to a number(ie. 10) so the legs are still away(so I can create shoes later) and the spaces between the legs need to increase in each row. I can print the spaces that move the legs away from the left side, but can't figure out how to create the slashes, the *s inbetween, the  or the other leg. Any help is appreciated.
This is what I have so far.

```
private void drawLegs()
{
    final char SPACE=' ';
    final int DISTANCE = 16;
    final int HEIGHT = 7;
    final char FWD='/';
    final char BWD='\\';

    for(int row=0; row<HEIGHT; row++)
         {
         int spaces = DISTANCE-row;
         for(int count=0;count<spaces;count++)
            {
              System.out.print(SPACE);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  Where is your code?  What have you tried?  If you expect someone to help you with your homework, please show some effort first.

Comment: If you can print a space, why can't you print a slash or a star? `print(' ')`, `print('/')`, `print('*')`. What is the exact nature of the problem you are facing? Keep in mind that this is not a code-writing service, so please show what you have done so far.

Comment: updated with what I have so far, I'm unsure of how to go with increasing the amount of * in each row and how to increase the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there will be a specific answer to your question, but I understand you can do as follows .

```
private static void drawLegs() {
        final char SPACE=' ';
        int DISTANCE = 16;
        final int HEIGHT = 7;
        final char FWD='/';
        final char BWD='\\';
        int starCount = 1;

        for (int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++) {
            int spaces = DISTANCE - row;
            for (int count = 0; count < spaces; count++) {
                System.out.print(SPACE);
            }
            System.out.print(FWD);
            for (int i = 0; i < starCount; i++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.print(FWD);
            for (int i = 0; i < starCount*2; i++) {
                System.out.print(SPACE);
            }
            System.out.print(BWD);
            for (int i = 0; i < starCount; i++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.print(BWD);
            DISTANCE--;
            starCount++;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you did not require loops, the simplest way would have been

```
private void drawLegs() 
{
    System.out.println("    /***/    \\***\\");
    System.out.println("  /****/      \\****\\");
    System.out.println("/*****/        \\*****\\");
}
```

So the way to proceed--you do not need to do this in your program, only to understand the problem-- is to write a table with the following values: (1) number of spaces before first leg, (2) number of stars in first leg, (3) number of spaces between the legs, and (4) number of stars in the 2nd leg (counted from the code above).

```
4  3  4  3
2  4  6  4
0  5  8  5
```

For each column, you have a starting value (the first line), and you should be able to figure the increment/decrement for each iteration of the loop.

The last thing you need is how to concatenate multiple characters.  This can be done with a `for` loop.  An an example, suppose you want to add 60 times the letter "A" at the end of a string:

```
String s = "";
for (int j=0; j<60; j++) s = s + "A";
```